# I want to create a custom function in jquery with few controls as parameters. How can I achieve this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have a checkbox (in ASP.NET) and want to enable/disable many ASP drop-down lists based on its `checked` attribute. Is it possible to do this using jQuery?

Here is my checkbox code:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chb1" OnCheckedChanged="enablecheck(this,"#<%=ddl1.ClientID%>");" Checked="false"  />
```

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(function enablecheck(chk,ddl) {
    $('[id$=chk]').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
           ddl.prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
            ddl.prop("disabled", true);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: next time please format your code preperly. try SOF help guide next time.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a CSS class to the ddls you want to toggle in the code, using the CssClass property. These can be addressed in jQuery using

```
$('.myDdlCssClass').prop('disabled', true);
```

I'm not sure if ddls are rendered as pure select field or get some wrapping elements in asp. So actually

```
$('.myDdlCssClass select')
```

May be the correct selector.

Comment: well I can enable / disable ddl but how do I pass it as a variable in jquery, as I need to do this for many ddls..